# Having problem generating a certificate request from a sql 2005 server

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to generate a certificate request from a sql 2005 / windows 2008 server, so that i can get a certificate made and thus enable encryption on my sql connections from clients.

On the server, i do:

- start -> run -> mmc
- add 'certificates' snapin
- choose 'computer account'
- choose 'local computer'
- Right click the Certificates > Personal folder in the left hand tree pane, choose All tasks > Request new certificate

But then it gives me the error:

```
Certificate Types are not available
You cannot request a certificate at this time because no certificate types are available.
The requested certificate template is not supported by this CA.
A valid certification authority configured to issue certificates based on this template
cannot be located, or the CA is not trusted.
```

Any ideas? We've got an enterprise CA, if that's worth knowing.
Thanks

Comment: This is related to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674160/using-encryptyes-in-a-sql-server-connection-string-provider-ssl-provider-e