# SSL Connection to database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oledb

My application need to establish secure connection with SQL Server 2008. Having enabled 'Force Encryption' in server side, following is my connection string from my C# application.

```
Initial Catalog=emp_test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***;Data Source=172.21.70.94;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Use Encryption for Data=True;Trust Server Certificate=True;
```

I did not provision any certificate in server - Hence I gave Trust Server Certificate=True, so that self signed server certificate is not validated.

But the connection is not established with following error.

> *Database error: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error.*

Without the two attributes related to security, it works fine.

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Can you try this for me? `Initial Catalog=emp_test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***;Data Source=172.21.70.94;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Encrypt=yes;`

Comment: Hey BigM, If I give Encrypt=yes, connection is established which I think should not happen without giving TrustServerCertificate. Hence it never took that attribute into account.

Comment: Please reference this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674160/using-encrypt-yes-in-a-sql-server-connection-string-provider-ssl-provider) which clearly shows that `Encrypt = yes` uses the certificate.

Comment: According to an answer on that post you can also add `TrustServerCertificate=True` to the connection string so that it's able to connect regardless of the cert.

Comment: As per this MSDN post - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131691.aspx), I am using an initialization string with **IDataInitialize** I may need to use attribute **Use Data for Encryption** instead of **Encrypt**. Similarly I need to use **Trust Server Certificate** instead of **TrustServerCertificate**.

Comment: is there a good reason you're not using the `SqlConnection` object?

Comment: Based on user db type (mssql or oracle) I construct connection string and establish the connection using oledbconnection.

Comment: Please go through this, it has complete explanation. [Establish DB connection by using Microsoft OLE DB provider and SQL Native OLE DB provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144914/establish-db-connection-by-using-microsoft-ole-db-provider-and-sql-native-ole-db)

Comment: Please go through the question asked before: [Establish DB connection by using Microsoft OLE DB provider and SQL Native OLE DB provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144914/establish-db-connection-by-using-microsoft-ole-db-provider-and-sql-native-ole-db)

Answer (score 7):

Using the `SqlConnection` object gives you two advantages. First, you can ensure the connection string will be built properly because you can use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to build it. Second, it's ***much*** faster than OLEDB.

To build this connection string ...

```
Initial Catalog=emp_test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***;Data Source=172.21.70.94;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Use Encryption for Data=True;Trust Server Certificate=True;
```

... using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` you would write some code like this ...

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "172.21.70.94";
builder.Encrypt = true;
builder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
builder.InitialCatalog = emp_test;
builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
builder.UserID = "sa";
builder.Password = "***";

var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
```

... the `Encrypt` property holds this definition in the .NET Framework ...

> Gets or sets a Boolean value that indicates whether SQL Server uses SSL encryption for all data sent between the client and server if the server has a certificate installed.

... the `TrustServerCertificate` property holds this definition in the .NET Framework ...

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the channel will be encrypted while bypassing walking the certificate chain to validate trust.

So I would say that this is the safest approach. You can ensure that the .NET Framework is going to build a connection string properly **and** you can get a good set of definitions surrounding what those properties mean in regards to certificates based on their definitions.

---

Now, since you connect to Oracle too, the best approach there would be to continue to build a OLEDB connection because you don't have much of a choice. But both connections are an `IDbConnection` and so you just have a factory that builds the right connection and returns an `IDbConnection`.

This means you get the best of both worlds, the performance and ease of the `SqlConnection` object and the abstraction of the `IDbConnection` so that your code doesn't have to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this BigM. I am going to try this. But I really dont know what is wrong with that oledb connection string attribute "Trust Server Certificate". It is not working at all.

Comment: @Praveen, I honestly don't know either, but that's why I think this is really the safest and easiest approach.