# https sql server connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, https

I have a application using SQL Server 2008, the connectionstring works fine without https.  However, when try to use https I get an error.  I'm using the below string, am I supposed to add something else instead?

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=https://ServerName\QA01;Initial Catalog=DB_QA;Uid=abc;Pwd=xyz" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

the only thing i did was add a https:// infront of the servername.  it works fine without it, the db team told me SSL is setup on the db server.

I get the following error:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not connect via HTTP, and not via HTTPS as well. In other words, you are using the wrong syntax here.

Have you enabled SSL encryption for your SQL Server? This link tells you how its done: [How to enable SSL encryption for an instance of SQL Server by using Microsoft Management Console](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-enable-ssl-encryption-for-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-microsoft-management-console-1c7ae22f-8518-2b3e-93eb-d735af9e344c)

Then, you use the `Encrypt` statement in the connection string:
[Using Encrypt=yes in a Sql Server connection string -> "provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674160/using-encrypt-yes-in-a-sql-server-connection-string-provider-ssl-provider)