# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user' error on asp.net core 1 db first

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following [this guide](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model) building a new core version of my current mvc 5 website. I have an existing sql database hosted on azure and I want to build the project database first. I followed the instructions but on the "reverse engineer you model" part I keep getting an error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Login failed
>   for user 'removed'.) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login
>   failed for user 'removed'.

The username and password are correct and working on the current project. This is the connection string:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=tcp:removed.database.windows.net,1433;
  Data Source=removed.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=removedCatalog;
  Persist Security Info=False;User ID=removedId@removed;Password=removedPass;
  Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;
  TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Any insight to what am I missing here?

Comment: This link could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674160/using-encrypt-yes-in-a-sql-server-connection-string-provider-ssl-provider  Two things to check are that the server name/IP in the connection string must exactly match the server name/IP in the certificate (@Moriarty) and @Vort3x made a point about servers with default certificates changing when they are restarted.

Comment: Things is, I can connect to it via VS Server Explorer with the same credentials. Also, the local version of the online site connects to the db with this exact connection string. So I believe it's something with the import proccess, not the string or the server.

Comment: That makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: Did this error occur when running "Scaffold-DbContext" command or somewhere else? I just tried that command and it works on my side.

Comment: it happens when I write it as is in the console

Comment: Really weird, I just compared your connection string with mine, nothing different except User ID and Password. I can confirm it works from my side, should not be related to the import process. One silly question, when copying the connection string from Azure portal, did you remove the braces "{}" around User ID and Password? they should not be there when using the connection string.

Comment: I did remove the braces, it's the same connection string as my current mvc 5 working website.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user exist on SQL Server, that the user is enabled, and has access (mapped) to the correct database.