# .Net core 2.1 and channel encryption

Tags: encryption, entity-framework-core, data-access, tde, .net-core-2.1

I had an .Net Core 2.1 application (with Visual Studio 2017 / SQL Server 2016). I am in the security phase. I search a solution to respect the GDPR norm.

TDE (Transparent Data Encryption) was chosen to encrypt the database (AlwaysEncrypted was not yet available for .Net Core). But with TDE, we encrypt the only database, not the channel between my database and my application. I use Entity Framework Core to access my database.

Do you know how it's possible to encrypt the channel between my database and my application?

Comment: There was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3674160/613130) response some years ago...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Encrypt=yes in a Sql Server connection string -> "provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674160/using-encrypt-yes-in-a-sql-server-connection-string-provider-ssl-provider)

Comment: Thank you very much xanatos and I am a Student for your responses.